# how to generate a unique id for each instance within a class in c++?

Tags: c++

I have attempted to create unique id's for all instances in my class, but this seems to be leading to errors later when trying to compile the program. this is the code i have written for the classes:

```
//this is GameObject.h
class GameObject
{
public:

    int instances;
    GameObject();
    void Display();
protected:
    int id;
};

//this is GameObject.cpp
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


GameObject::GameObject()
{
    instances = this->id; //is this the correct way to generate the unique id?

}
```

Comment: You are not initialising `id`.

Comment: Not initializing `id` is not much of a problem compared with the fact that the code posted doesn't increment (or otherwise modify) it!

Comment: it is modified elsewhere, through using templates and in the main, should i include these?

Answer (score 6):

Do something like this:

```
class GameObject
{
public:
    int id;
    GameObject() : id(++s_id) {}
protected:
    static std::atomic<int> s_id;
};

// in the .cpp file:
std::atomic<int> GameObject::s_id;
```

This way, each object constructed will get the next id, starting from 1 (because the static will be initialized to zero by default).  It probably doesn't matter what value you start from.  You might want to take care when writing copy constructors, assignment operators, and the like.  Finally, note that the atomic type is part of C++11; if you don't have support for it you can say "boost" instead of "std" there.  Either version will give you thread safety, in case you need it.

Answer (score 4):

No, each instance of `GameObject` will have its own (uninitialized) instance of `id`. There needs to be a shared incrementing `id` instance available to all instances of `GameObject`. One mechanism to achieve this to use a `static` class variable. If threads are involved you need to synchronize access to the `static` variable:

```
class GameObject
{
protected:
    static int id;
};

int GameObject::id; // defaults to zero and should be added to
                    // exactly one .cpp file only.

GameObject::GameObject() : instances(GameObject::id++) {}
```

Another alternative is to use [`boost::uuid`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/uuid/):

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>
using boost::lexical_cast;
using boost::uuids::uuid;
using boost::uuids::random_generator;

class GameObject
{
public:
    string instances;
    GameObject() : instances(make_uuid_());
    void Display();
private:
    string make_uuid_()
    {
        return lexical_cast<string>((random_generator())());
    }
};
```

Comment: this does not work as id is linked to other header files and id has to be protected.

Comment: @W_K, define the `GameObject::id` in one `.cpp` file and it does not have to be `protected`.

Comment: @W_K: What's the problem with it being `protected`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, (unsure if you are speaking to me) but I did not say there was a problem with `protected`, just it did not have to be and it does not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit my design that i am following states that it has to be protected.

Comment: @W_K, then just change it to `protected`.

Comment: @W_K: So make it `protected`. What is the problem?

Comment: (Seems strange that your design enforces an access level but otherwise contains completely incorrect ideas about how to go about this.)

Comment: well i have put id to protected, well you see, when i go to compile the whole program, i get a 'build succeeded' but then i get a CXX0030 error problem where it breaks, and i found that this is in the gameobject class, not being able to find my instances or id. hope that makes sense? and i wasn't sure if i was generating the id properly.

Comment: @hmjd: Why would that be directed at you. I responded to W_K's comment about design, with a response about design.

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct because `id` merely has an **indeterminate value**(*since it is uninitialized*) not unique value.

You could address of an object as the unique identifier. Each object in C++ is placed at an different address. However, if you need to identify each object this way there is something amiss in your design.

Comment: It can be useful. e.g. a timer implementation

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, true. My comment was misleading. It was specific to the code which OP shows in the example. It seems OP wants to identify each game object which seems like bad design in implementation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Certainly helps to atleast raise the point.